# Need Assistance with Deployment Issue for MERN Full-Stack Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, netlify

Hello fellow developers,

I am seeking assistance with an issue I'm encountering while deploying my MERN (MongoDB, Express.js, React.js, Node.js) full-stack application. The website is currently accessible at the following URL: [website URL](https://jdnblog.netlify.app/).

Here are the details and links related to my project:

Frontend GitHub Repository: GitHub - [Frontend](https://github.com/jondereck/blog_client)
Backend GitHub Repository: GitHub - [Backend](https://github.com/jondereck/blog_api)
The problem I'm facing is that the website functions correctly on my local machine. However, when I try to access it from other devices, such as another PC or cellphone, the content from the database is not being displayed. Specifically, the website is not able to fetch and show the database content.

To provide additional context, here are some key points about my setup:

Backend: The backend is built using Express.js and Node.js, with MongoDB as the database.
Frontend: The frontend is deployed on Netlify, and I have confirmed that it loads successfully on my local machine.
Deployment Environment: The backend is deployed on a separate server.

If you have experience with the MERN stack, deployment processes, or have encountered similar issues, I would greatly appreciate your expertise in resolving this problem. Please let me know if any specific code snippets, error messages, or further details would be helpful in diagnosing the issue.

Thank you all in advance for your time, assistance, and valuable insights. I am eagerly looking forward to your suggestions and guidance.

Based on initial observations, I suspect that the issue might be related to one of the
CORS Configuration: As the frontend and backend are hosted on different domains, it's crucial to configure Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) properly. I need guidance on ensuring that the backend API allows cross-origin requests from the Netlify domain.

Comment: first, I suspected it to be CORS related, but since it's accessible already but only the database content to being displayed, It's alleged to be your database connection, if you set up the connection using localhost, it's 100% guaranteed that it's the reasons it's working locally. you can't expect magic when the database is not uploaded to a cloud server and configured as to fetch data from there. and also from your front-end link, I can see you're still making requests to http://localhost:4000, which is not an online/active global accessible url.

Comment: You're making requests to `http://localhost:4000` instead of to your API URL. Depending on the setup, the API URL may share the same domain as the client `https://jdnblog.netlify.app/`, but you'll have some sort of routing rules to direct traffic to client vs API. I don't know how you're serving it nor how you're differentiating client vs API routes, so it's hard to give more specific help. That said, this env `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` should be updated to use the netlify remote URL instead of localhost.

Comment: Two other call outs are that it appears that you're using `nodemon` to serve your API. This is okay for development, but it shouldn't be used for production. Typically, you'll compile the API's JS to a `build` directory, then run the server via a package.json script like `"start": "node build/index.js"`. The other call out is that you **will** run into problems when nodemon is running the server and you upload a file to the `uploads` folder -- nodemon will restart the process! You'll want to create a [nodemon config](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files) to ignore the `uploads` folder.

Comment: I forgot to update the API URL in my .env file. Once I made the necessary changes, everything fell into place, and my application started working flawlessly. Your expertise truly saved the day!

Thank you for the time answering my question, all of the comments are noted and applied the recommendation.